# Storyboard iOS - How to give top margin as a % of screen size instead of static value top pin margin?

Tags: ios, storyboard, constraints, ios-autolayout

I want to top margin auto dynamic according the size of the screen.Like aspect ratio work for height and width.

Same way I want top margin as a some % from top instead of static pixel value top pin margin.

Comment: You should do that in code. Get the screen height and then change constraint.

Comment: use spacerview and give equal height

Comment: Thanks, But can we do it without code?LIke % height instead of static height ?

Comment: LIke % top margin instead of static  ?

Comment: yes ... without code ... spacerview is what you need

Comment: Can you please share a link.From where I can read about it ?

Comment: @Vishalsingh thats too broad .. but if possible I'll post an answer tomorrow

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 4):

One way to get proportional spacing is to link the view to the centre of its superview.

First, create a constraint that makes your inner view centered vertically in its container.  Then, change the constraint's multiplier to something other than one so that it's positioned however far from centre you want it (0.2 or whatever for the top).